# AudioUnitRender fails with GenericOutput (-10877 /Invalid Element)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I am basically trying to obtain the samples produced by an `AUGraph` using a `GenericOutput Node` and a call to `AudioUnitRender`. As a starting point for my program I used the `MixerHost` example by Apple and changed the `outputNode` as follows.

```
AudioComponentDescription iOUnitDescription;
iOUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
iOUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput;
iOUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
iOUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
iOUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;
```

Later when I want to obtain my samples, I call

```
AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  ioActionFlags = kAudioOfflineUnitRenderAction_Render;
AudioTimeStamp        inTimeStamp = {0};

inTimeStamp.mHostTime = mach_absolute_time();
inTimeStamp.mFlags =   kAudioTimeStampSampleHostTimeValid;

result = AudioUnitRender (
                 ioUnit,
                 &ioActionFlags,
                 &inTimeStamp,
                 1,
                 1024,
                 ioData
                 );
```

which yields an

> "-10877 / Invalid Element"

error. My assumption is, that the error comes from not setting the `inTimeStamp.mSampleTime` field correctly. To be honest, I have not found  a way to find out the sample time other than `AudioQueueDeviceGetCurrentTime`, which I cannot use, since I do not use an `AudioQueue`. However changing the `ioActionFlag` to  `kAudioTimeStampHostTimeValid` does not change the the error behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The error pertaining to the element (AKA 'bus') refers to the 4th argument (1) to your AudioUnitRender call.  The Generic Output unit only has one element/bus: 0 which has an input, output and global scope.  If you pass 0 to the call instead of 1 for the element #, that error should disappear.